# Invoke command when property changes within ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: reactiveui

I have the following *working* code, but I'm not sure if I've actually done this correctly or if I'm bastardizing ReactiveUI.

```cs
ctor()
{
    var saveFieldCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<FieldObject>(ExecuteSaveField);
    Fields.ToObservableChangeSet()
        .ToCollection()
        .Subscribe(x => x.ForEach(
            f => f.WhenAny(y => y.IsActive, change => change.Sender)
                .Skip(1)
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .InvokeCommand(saveFieldCommand)));
}

private async Task ExecuteSaveField(FieldObject field) 
    => await  _fieldDataService.Save(field).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Is there a more correct way of calling the save command whenever the `IsActive` property changes on a property within an `ObservableCollection<T>`? I'm concerned about potential memory leaks on the subscription and also concerned about the `.ForEach` in there.

Answer (score -1):

You should create `FieldObjectViewModel`, then transform `FieldObject` to `FieldObjectViewModel`.

`FieldObjectViewModel` will handle `SaveCommand` when `IsActive` change.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't really get me where i need to go. The code snippet above is a part of my ViewModel, and that model contains the list of fields. This question is more about ReactiveUI and how to turn those changes into an observable stream.